# PHP checks cookie value for response, Response won't revert back after cookie is cleared

Tags: php, if-statement, cookies, echo

So I've scoured w3schools and this fine website for some time but I can't figure this out.

I have a script that creates a cookie in the users session upon loading the browser, and another script that will check the value of said cookie and respond with 2 echo's depending on the value.

Script to create the cookie is:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "CTF";
$cookie_value = "ChangeThis";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400, "/", NULL);
}
?>
```

My IF check for the values is as follows:

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE[$cookie_value] = "CTF") {
    echo "Congratulations. Your token code is 4HeWPzK63Lf5NkGS";
    } else { 
    echo "Your cookie is not set yet.";
    }
?>
```

The code works, and when the cookie is changed to CTF it echo's the correct line. However, when I then delete the cookie and refresh the page, essentially resetting the cookie back to the value of "ChangeThis", the first echo still appears on the page.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `if` condition. You have used `=` instead of `==`. You are assigning the value instead of comparing. The condition checks if the assignment is successful or not. What you need is the below statement:

```
if($_COOKIE[$cookie_name] == "CTF")
```

Also, the cookie value is not "CTF", that's the cookie name, you should compare with the value you are setting it to.

Comment: Furthermore it should be something like if($_COOKIE["CTF"] != "ChangeThis")
CTF is the cookie name, not the cookie value

Comment: @maalls you are right.. I have updated the answer.. Then OP should also check for the value.

Comment: Ah yes, Can't believe I overlooked that. For the IF statement where it checks the cookie value, I originally want it to check whether the cookie is value has been changed (I'm creating a CTF scenario essentially). So would it be ok to leave it as this:

    IF($_COOKIE["CTF"]="CTF"

Comment: `if($_COOKIE["CTF"]="CTF"` would always be true unless for some reason the assignment fails.. you are confusing the assignment with the comparison.

Comment: Yes just realised when I went to look at it again. Is it possible to have the IF statement check the value of the cookie rather than the name itself?

Comment: Go through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). The variable `$_COOKIE["CTF"]` will return the cookie value with the name "CTF"..

Comment: yes that's perfect! thanks guys! clearly got a lot more reading to do.

Comment: Accept as answer and close!